# Webhost firewall blocking paypal ipn ssl?

Tags: php

Error log:

```
    [07-Mar-2016 23:26:23 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/domeofli/public_html/test/payments.php on line 81
[07-Mar-2016 23:26:23 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://www.paypal.com:443 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in /home/domeofli/public_html/test/payments.php on line 81
[07-Mar-2016 23:30:40 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/domeofli/public_html/test/payments.php on line 81
[07-Mar-2016 23:30:40 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://www.paypal.com:443 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in /home/domeofli/public_html/test/payments.php on line 81
```

Line 81:

```
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

So, what do you think? Could it be my dodgy web host (it's very dodgy, i'm just here for the low price of $5 a year lol), i tested out my script about 5-10 times and only once did my information get sent into the database (5 minutes later).

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSL library has to be installed to open ssl:// URL. Check it with a phpinfo() call.

Comment: I just tested the script again, it worked that time around, i'm confused i guess it's just my dodgy web host?